# Cannot create stored procedures with EXECUTE AS using a Certificate-based Principal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, impersonation, digital-certificate

I am trying to re-create an expired certificate which was being used on our servers to create principles and then those principles were being used with impersonation to execute stored procedures.

This is what I'm doing (of course a lot more complex on production, but this exact test also fails).

```
Use ReportingDb
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE MyCertTest ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'acrazygoodpassword'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Stored procedure signing for Reports'
      ,EXPIRY_DATE = '11/18/2019';
GO

BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyCertTest TO FILE = 'D:\MyCertTest.CER';
GO

CREATE USER TestReportUser
FROM CERTIFICATE MyCertTest;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','TestReportUser';

GRANT AUTHENTICATE
   TO TestReportUser;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE
   TO TestReportUser;
GO


USE Master;
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE MyCertTest
FROM FILE = 'D:\MyCertTest.CER';
GO
CREATE USER TestReportUser
FROM CERTIFICATE MyCertTest;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','TestReportUser';

GRANT AUTHENTICATE
   TO TestReportUser;

GRANT EXECUTE
   TO TestReportUser;
GO


use ReportingDb
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Reports_DC_Project_sp
WITH EXECUTE AS 'TestReportUser'
AS
SELECT 1
GO
```

Not sure if I really need the master db piece. This is all successful until creating the stored procedure, then:

> Msg 15517, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Reports_DC_Project_sp, Line 47
>   Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "TestReportUser" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

I've also tried creating the stored procedure with EXECUTE AS 'dbo'. That works fine... then adding the signature to the stored procedure and finally altering the stored procedure to execute as my cert user. Same error on last step.

Is there a setting/step I'm missing?

Comment: Hi there. Have you been able to get this to work? I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41421145/577765) below that explains why this  is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

use [databasename]

GO

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'

GO

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to re-create an expired certificate which was being used on our servers to create principles...

Um, no. Certificate expiration dates are not checked / validated when creating principals from them, nor even when using them with [ADD SIGNATURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181700.aspx) to sign a module.

> and then those principles were being used with impersonation to execute stored procedures.

Definitely no. This was not happening because it is technically impossible to happen; Certificate and Assymetric Key -based principals cannot be used for Impersonation.

> Not sure if I really need the master db piece.

No, it is not. It doesn't do anything in this usage. If you wanted to associated server (i.e. instance)-level permissions (even membership in the `sysadmin` role) to the Certificate and every module signed by it, then you would restore the Certificate into `master` as you have shown, but then you would create a Login from that Certificate and grant the appropriate permissions to it. Creating a User in `master` doesn't do anything unless there is something specific in the `master` Database that a User would need to interact with. But as far as your test is concerned, it is entirely irrelevant.

Also, granting `AUTHENTICATE` to the Certificate-based is entirely irrelevant and useless since Certificate and Asymmetric Key -based principals cannot authenticate. At all. Ever.

> then adding the signature to the stored procedure and finally altering the stored procedure to execute as my cert user.

Even if it was possible to EXECUTE AS a Certificate or Asymmetric Key -based principal, it would be pointless to add the signature *before* altering the Stored Procedure with the `EXECUTE AS` clause since that `ALTER` statement would automatically invalidate the signature. Signatures are automatically dropped when either the definition of the module, or the `EXECUTE` AS clause it changed. You would have to re-sign the module after the `ALTER` statement, so no use in adding the signature beforehand.

> Is there a setting/step I'm missing?

You aren't missing a step as there is no way to make this work. However, you are misunderstanding the concepts here. Impersonation (via `EXECUTE AS`) and module signing (via `ADD SIGNATURE`) are mutually exclusive. In fact, module signing pretty much replaces / obsoletes Impersonation.

Certificate-based and Asymmetric Key-based principals (Logins and Users) cannot be impersonated or authenticated. Hence you get the error for (emphasis added):

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "TestReportUser" does not exist, **this type of principal cannot be impersonated**, or you do not have permission.

That is part of what makes module signing a more secure framework than Impersonation.

So get rid of the following:

1. `GRANT AUTHENTICATE`
2. all of the statements being executed in `master`
3. the `EXECUTE AS` clause

and you will be fine.